# iOS: Socket communication for sending image data

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am developing an iOS socket program, using which i want to programmatically send an UIImage data to a server. This is my requirement, i can't send through any other communication channel, i need to send through Socket communication only. I have got UIImage NSData. I have got sample socket communication program from [this link](http://www.tekritisoftware.com/sites/default/files/Socket_Programing_for_IOS.pdf).

I need your help for understanding the following points,
1. How can i send this UIImage data to a server? Can i use the code from the above link? Or Can I use CocoaAsyncSocket framework itself for achieving this?
2. How do I create a server component to receive this data? I am familiar with Eclipse, Java and Javascript. I have created a servlet project in Eclipse for Tomcat server access? Can I use that for this purpose? (or) Please suggest me the steps involved for this?
3. I want to just send a simple string to my server through my iOS socket program and receive on the server end, for testing now, and then go for sending image data. Could someone please suggest.

I need your help please!

Comment: Where exactly is the problem? Getting the data from an image, sending it trough socket, parsing it on the server side or somewhere else? Does the server know it will get an image or you have to embed the image data with some overhead? Do you also write the server or does it expect to get the data in some particular way?

Comment: I am able to get the nsdata from an UIImage, i need to send this data to my server through socket connection. I am looking for, 1.) How to send this data to my server, some example code would be appreciated. 2.) How I can view that image data on the server end?

Comment: For sending the data to the server using socket check the connection that spider1983 had provided - CocoaAsyncSocket should make your life easier - but there is some learning curve involved. As for getting the image back on the serverside it depends on what kind of server are you running: php, c++? In any case: you will have to know (and you do) the format of the image (png, jpeg). Then google around for: get image from blob (blob being common name for a chunk of data representing somthing, ie. image)

Comment: You might want to expand you question with some details otherwise it will be closed. Also I'd suggest small steps: first try to transfer only a simple string to the server, then work your way trough to sending the image - larger chunck can be a bit tricky.

Comment: This is great info. If i send a string to test, how would have received on the server end? Could you give in few words please? Is it possible to run a server in eclipse project and receive through this program?

Comment: In what language are you planning to write your server? Eclipse is an IDE... Is it gonna be c++ or something else?

Comment: Java related language is the preference language always. I had created a small servlet project for server access, will I be able to use the same?

Comment: I never used Java so I can't help you with that. But you should divide your question into separate "atomic" tasks/questions. Try to make some research on each of them and when you get stuck at a specific point - post a question on SO. If you post a broad question like this all you are gonna get is a closed question and a bunch of downvotes.

Comment: Hi rokjarc, I'll expand the actual question. But, I just want the steps to have a server component and receive this simple string through iOS socket program like how can a server component be created in any language and receive this string from client. I'll need to decide the language next.

Comment: In that link that spider1983 provided are examples on how to make a server on Mac and a client in iOs - you can for example start with echo server on Mac. You can first start testing in local WiFi - thus using your computers LAN IP as a server address.

Comment: Thank you so much to both of you! I have another query related to CocoaAsync, please help if possible, its here-> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20997480/ios-cocoaasyncsocket-image-data-not-sending-from-client-cocoaasyncsocket

Comment: @Stella.. I have this same issue now.. I want to send the image from iOS through socket an wants to receive it back at receiver end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start from this framework https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket

it has good documentation also regarding setting connection and communicating with socket you can google for that, but for your purpose i guess a combination of above framework and Bonjour will do the trick.

Comment: Hi, This app will be released to Appstore, so millions of users may download and use it. If i use Bonjour service, it will be restricted to local area network right? I can't send data packets through socket communication directly to my server machine ignoring bonjour? Any advise please?

Comment: @spider1983: OP mentions that he wants to send the images to the server. Why would Bonjour be needed for this task? It seems we have a known URL for the server in this case... As for CocoaAsyncSocket - good framework.

Comment: Hi Rokjarc, You are right.